# Find K-shortest Path in Orientdb

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, shortest-path

I am new to OrientDB and I am trying to find top k shortest path in my graph.So I am creating my algorithm by applying from Yen's algorithm but I do not know how to use it to work in OrientDB ,or is there another ways to find K-shortest path in Orient Graph?
How should I do ?

Thank for all helping :]

Comment: Please add some code you worked with and search before asking a question

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the shortest path (only the shorter) could use directly the function present in OrientDB ShortestPath:
[image]

Comment: Thank for your comment @Isavio I know that OrientDB have the function to find shortest path and I have used those function to find the shortest path in my graph but I would like to use another shortest path like second or third shortest path.For now I am trying to apply Yen algorithm to find but I do know how to plug it to work in OrientDB. Sorry about my english skill If I make misunderstanding :)

Comment: No problem for your English :), okay so you're trying to apply alghoritm Yen (is this right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm ) to OrientDB. I also do some tests trying to make a Java class that implements this algorithm.

Comment: You will probably want to look at the Java code that implements shortestPath(): it is in the github repository file: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/graphdb/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/graph/sql/functions/OSQLFunctionShortestPath.java